# Beginners Java Blue J returning a String in a method

Tags: java, methods, return, bluej

Hi i want my method to search for a book via an id and return the title, the method works perfectly when i printLn but i need it to be returned instead i am getting an error : incompatible types unexpected return value, what do i need to do ?

EDit
i have now changed the void to string however i am still getting an error : missing return value

Thanks in advance.

```
  public void returnByBookID(int enterBookId)
    {
          Iterator<Book> it = books.iterator();
          while(it.hasNext()) {
          Book books =  it.next();
          if(books.idNumber == (enterBookId)){

          return books.title ;
         }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to the following:

```
public String returnByBookID(int enterBookId) {

    Iterator<Book> it = books.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Book books =  it.next();
        if(books.idNumber == (enterBookId)){

            return books.title ;
        }
    }
    return "ID not found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method return type is `void`, change it to `String` to return the book title.

```
public String returnByBookID(int enterBookId){
.....................
..............
........

 return books.title ;

}
```

Also `return statement` is inside `if condition`,

```
if(books.idNumber == (enterBookId)){
          return books.title ;
       }
```

either take empty String and assign the book title to it and return that or return null or emty string in the last.

```
public String returnByBookID(int enterBookId)
String bookTitle = "";
    {
          Iterator<Book> it = books.iterator();
          while(it.hasNext()) {
          Book books =  it.next();
          if(books.idNumber == (enterBookId)){
             bookTitle = books.title ;
         }
      }

   return bookTitle ;
  }
```